# Как сделать заливку в Python Turtle?

Tags: python

Как сделать заливку в Python Turtle?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы указать начало заливки задаем команду `turtle.begin_fill()`, а чтобы закончить `turtle.end_fill()`
сначала указываем начало заливки
дальше перемещаем в конечную точку черепашку
и заканчиваем заливку